# Открыть сетевой диск через cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

Подключен сетевой диск от Яндекс.Диск без установки самого диска от Яндекс. После перезагрузки системы он отключен, для его включения необходимо его открыть. В командной строке пытаюсь его открыть командой cd /d y: но в ответ пишет что системе не удаётся найти указанный путь. На локальные диски этой командой я перехожу. Наверно сетевой диск открывается другой командой, как мне его открыть? Нужно что-бы через командную строку он подключился так же как если бы я его открыл через проводник. Ещё нужно что бы при переходе я ввёл данные учётной записи если они не сохранены.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал net user y:\ и вывелась информация о диске. Как мне его открыть и если учётные данные не сохранены открыть введя их в параметрах открытия в cmd?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если подключить диск через проводник или Total Commander то вы не сможете открыть его через cmd командой cd. Что бы его открыть необходимо подключится и/или через командную строку путём что дан в ответе. После чего команда cd сработает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В сети советуют так:

```
net use Y: https://webdav.yandex.ru password /user:email_address /persistent:yes
```

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: А так тоже не работает cd /d y:\ ?

Comment: Системе не удаётся найти указанный диск

Comment: net use https://webdav.yandex.ru \\update - команда выполнена успешно но в командной строке не переходит на сетевой диск

Comment: cd \\https://webdav.yandex.ru\update - cmd.exe не поддерживает пути UNC в качестве текущей папки.

Comment: изменил свой ответ

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос